# Docker - Install PDO Driver for PHP + Nginx

Tags: php, docker, pdo, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql
```

Then I have in my docker-compose.yml file:

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./frontend:/var/www/html
    - ./api:/var/www/html/api
    - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  links:
    - php
mysql:
  image: mariadb
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
  volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
php:
  image: php:7-fpm
  volumes:
    - ./frontend:/var/www/html
    - ./api:/var/www/html/api
  links:
    - mysql
```

Then In my PHP Code I have:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=example", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Which when I go to connect to my database I get:

> Connection failed: could not find driver

How would I download the PDO driver using this docker setup?

Comment: Is it actually trying to connect to localhost via the code? If so, I don't see any of the containers attaching to the host net. Just wanted to clarify before I hazard a guess. Is the code supposed to be executed in PHP FPM?

Comment: I have php linked from the web image.

Right now I can go to localhost and it serves up php pages just fine, but attempting to use PDO to connect to my database will not work because of the missing driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems:

1.) The Dockerfile should be like this to install pdo driver:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql
```

2.) To connect to mysql from php you need to use the name from the dockerfile (mysql) not localhost, like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=example", root, password);
```